# Find records for students missing a class

Tags: sql, correlated-subquery

I have two tables, one that flags a user as having passed a course, and a list of courses per job code. I'm trying to query to return a record for all users that are missing classes.

Here are the tables:

```
Attended
--------
empid   jobcode classcode   grade  
555     1       100         A  
555     1       101         A  
444     2       200         A  

JobClassCode
--------
jobcode classcode
1       100
1       101
1       102
2       100
2       200
3       300
3       301
```

I started with this query to find classes with a missing user:

```
select * from attended at
right outer join jobcodeclass jc on at.jobcode = jc.jobcode and at.classcode = jc.classcode
```

I then tried to take that to build a correlated subquery, but I don't see a way to return both the user ID and missing course ID:

```
select * from jobcodeclass oq where classcode in (select jc.classcode from attended at 
right outer join jobcodeclass jc on at.jobcode = jc.jobcode 
and at.classcode = jc.classcode and jc.jobcode = oq.jobcode 
and oq.classcode = jc.classcode and empid is null)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate all the possible classes that each employee needs by joining on the `jobcode`.  The see which ones the student attended:

```
select ej.empid, ej.jobcode, jss.classcode
from (select distinct empid, jobcode from attended) ej join
     JobClassCode jcc
     on jcc.jobcode = ej.jobcode left join
     attended a
     on a.empid= e.empid and a.jobcode = ej.jobcode and
        a.classcode = jcc.classcode
where a.empid is null;
```

If you just need the employees, use `select distinct ej.empid`.

Comment: This got me what I needed, thank you very much for your help.